# Passing Parameters to Method, Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Below is my codebehind. I brand new to using Xamarin, watched a few things but Id rather not learn the XAML side at this moment and thought I could just do it code only thinking I had enough experience coding in general to feel my way through.

Im simply trying to access the values of the view's elements in my submit method.

Most things I find online have some XAML integration with setting bindings etc, I even saw one code example along the lines of

```
myButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty,new Binding(){Source=NameEntry,Path="LoginCommand"});
myButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty,new Binding(){Source=NameEntry,Path="Text"});
```

But in [this example](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53638/data-bind-button-commandparameterproperty-to-entry-text-in-code-behind) I didn't really know how to correlate it to what I'm doing.

So here's what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Security.Cert;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Appointments
{
    public partial class AppointmentsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public AppointmentsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Content = NewAppointment();
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);
        }

        View NewAppointment()
        {

            var name = new Entry { Placeholder = "John Doe" };
            var email = new Entry { Placeholder = "jdoe1337@yahoo.com" };
            var phone = new Entry { Placeholder = "123-456-7890" };
            var doctor = new Entry { Placeholder = "Dr. Who" };
            var date = new DatePicker
            {
                MinimumDate = System.DateTime.Now,
                MaximumDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(90)
            };
            var time = new TimePicker() { Time = new System.TimeSpan(9, 0, 0) };
            var reasonLabel = new Label() { Text = "Reason For Visit" };
            var reason = new Editor();

            Button makeAppt = new Button
            {
                Text = "Submit"
            };


            makeAppt.Clicked += new EventHandler(OnSubmit);
            //makeAppt.Clicked += OnSubmit(); // tried this but get an error about converting void to event handler.

            return new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    name,
                    email,
                    phone,
                    doctor,
                    date,
                    time,
                    reasonLabel,
                    reason,
                    makeAppt
                }
            };
        }

        void OnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // want to do stuff here with
            // name.Text
            // phone.Text
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this `makeAppt.Clicked += OnSubmit;`

Comment: all of your element references (name, email, phone, etc) are local to NewAppointment and will not be accessible to other methods.  You need to make them class level variables.

Comment: Perfect, I think I left the parentheses in there because I was trying to pass it the values I was wanting to manipulate. Then when I failed I forgot to delete them.

Comment: Added as an answer and explained some more, please accept if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about at first is used when you are working with data binding. The rest of your code does not show this, so I will assume that you do not want to use this right now, just like you don't want to use XAML yet.

Looking at your code the most apparent error is that you need to leave the parenthesis out. So change it to `makeAppt.Clicked += OnSubmit;`. The signature will have to match, if it doesn't it will give you a compile time error.

Now, if you want to access the values like `name` and `email`, you will have to put them in scope. As you have declared them now, they are only available within the `NewAppointment` method. You probably want to move them up to the class level, so you can also use them on the `OnSubmit` method. With all the changes, it will probably look more like this (not tested):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Security.Cert;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Appointments
{
    public partial class AppointmentsPage : ContentPage
    {
        // Moved all control instances to here
        Entry name = new Entry { Placeholder = "John Doe" };
        Entry email = new Entry { Placeholder = "jdoe1337@yahoo.com" };
        Entry phone = new Entry { Placeholder = "123-456-7890" };
        Entry doctor = new Entry { Placeholder = "Dr. Who" };

        DatePicker date = new DatePicker
        {
            MinimumDate = System.DateTime.Now,
            MaximumDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(90)
        };

        TimePicker time = new TimePicker() { Time = new System.TimeSpan(9, 0, 0) };
        Label reasonLabel = new Label() { Text = "Reason For Visit" };
        Editor reason = new Editor();

        public AppointmentsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Content = NewAppointment();
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);
        }

        View NewAppointment()
        {
            Button makeAppt = new Button
            {
                Text = "Submit"
            };

            makeAppt.Clicked += OnSubmit;

            return new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    name,
                    email,
                    phone,
                    doctor,
                    date,
                    time,
                    reasonLabel,
                    reason,
                    makeAppt
                }
            };
        }

        void OnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Now you can access your controls here, like this
            var newName = name.Text;
        }
    }
}
```